# Git diff two branches with a dot (.) in the name

Tags: git

When I run `git diff origin/r35.2..origin/r35.3` I get:

```
fatal: bad revision 'origin/r35.2..origin/r35.3'
```

How do I escape the dots in the name?

Comment: Did you try `git diff origin/r35\.2..origin/r35\.3`?

Comment: duh… that worked… thanks! Add an answer and I'll mark it

Comment: No escape should be required at all: this should just work. I see the `fatal: bad revision` output above, but it should not be occurring if both names are valid. Note, however, that `git diff X..Y` means *exactly the same thing* as `git diff X Y`, so you could replace the two dots with one space and it would not appear visually-ambiguous. (This "two dots equals space" thing is only true for `git diff`, not for `git log` for example.)

Comment: hmh… maybe it's a bug then… I'm using git 2.17.0 on macos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Escape with backslashes `\`.

`git diff origin/r35\.2..origin/r35\.3`